# Command line jabber chat clients for windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, chat, jabber

I only use Google Talk, and was wondering if there were any jabber command line clients for windows? I prefer command-line as I use it a lot on a day to day basis, and it seems much easier. The client can be either some windows only program, or a python/ruby/perl script. anything is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### MCabber

[MCabber](http://mcabber.com/) is a (quite popular, I think) text-mode client.

> mcabber is a small Jabber console client.
> mcabber includes features such as SASL/SSL/TLS support, MUC (Multi-User Chat) support, history logging, command completion, OpenPGP encryption, OTR (Off-the-Record Messaging) support, dynamic modules and external action triggers.

### Finch (Pidgin)

The multi-protocol client Pidgin offers a text client: [Finch](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch).

> Finch is a console-based IM program that lets you sign on to AIM, Jabber, MSN, Yahoo!, and other IM networks.

### GNU Freetalk

There is also [Freetalk](http://www.gnu.org/software/freetalk/):

> Freetalk is a console based Jabber client. It features a readline interface with completion of buddy names, commands, and even ordinary English words. Freetalk is extensible, configurable, and scriptable through a Guile interface.

### irssi-xmpp

A plugin for irssi (which is an IRC client): [irssi-xmpp](http://cybione.org/%7Eirssi-xmpp/)

> irssi-xmpp is an irssi plugin to connect to the Jabber network.
>
> Its aim is to provide a good integration in this text-based irc client and a good support of XMPP (the Jabber protocol).

### Poezio

https://poez.io/en/

> Poezio is a free console XMPP client (the protocol on which the Jabber IM network is built).

### Profanity

http://www.profanity.im/

> Profanity is a simple Jabber client written in C using ncurses and libstrophe, inspired by Irssi.

Comment: "console client" isn't eqial to "command line client"

Answer (score 0):

[CenterIM5](http://www.centerim.org/index.php/Main_Page) supports XMPP (and GTalk) as well. It has a nice curses interface but requires you to type `ctrl+x` to send messages.  That was a show stopper for me: too much effort. Your mileage might vary.